# how to search datetime with sql searching between two rows?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to search rows in the database by range of date and time. Each row will have a timewritten but if the range i pick would include in the range between the two rows would include in the result. Doesn't pull the previous row  before the first one. Anybody have any suggestions?

values in Table:

```
tempTable
-------------------------------
rowId   timewritten
1       2019-02-05 22:14:30.200
2       2019-02-05 22:16:39.513
3       2019-02-05 22:37:27.437
4       2019-02-05 22:58:21.343
5       2019-02-05 23:00:50.400
-------------------------------
```

```
select * 
    from temptable
    where TimeWritten >= '2019-02-05 22:20:00' 
        and timewritten <= '2019-02-05 22:57:00'
```

```
tempTable
-------------------------------
rowId   timewritten
1       2019-02-05 22:16:39.513
2       2019-02-05 22:37:27.437
3       2019-02-05 22:58:21.343
-------------------------------
```

Comment: 22:16 and 22:58 are outside the range. what is your question again?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get one row before and after (if any), you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(timewritten, 1, timewritten) over (order by timewritten) as prev_TimeWritten,
             lead(timewritten, 1, timewritten) over (order by timewritten) as next_TimeWritten
      from temptable t
     ) t
where next_TimeWritten >= '2019-02-05 22:20:00' and
      prev_timewritten <= '2019-02-05 22:57:00';
```